# how to access tableviewcell by indexpath in my function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkmark

I've got a tableview and I need to somehow save the ones that has been checked before. I've save the indexpath of those which has been check in an array. now I have the code below and I don't know how to define "cell" ( items are NSindexpath ).
I've already tried this but it returns nill and doesn't work :
 let cell = super.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(items)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    for items in indexpatharray{
        if !indexpatharray.isEmpty{
        let cell = 

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
        cell!.selectionStyle = .None


    }
```

I've already tried this but it returns nill and doesn't work :
    let cell = super.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(items)

Comment: You won't be able to access cells in `viewWillAppear` as the tableview won't have rendered any cells yet.  You should use your checked items array in `cellforRowAtIndexPath` and set/clear the checkmark as required.  This will also allow you to handle cell reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an access to cell, you can try this:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Comment: when I do this cell still returns nill while my indexpatharray is not empty

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use data instead of cell, once the cell is marked, you should mark the data which behind the cell.And when you need to know which is marked, you look for the data not the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I amn't sure if you can call these delegate and datasource methods in ViewWillAppear() but you shouldn't.
If you say that you have an array of the saved indexPaths, then what you can do is - 
Set the accessory type of the prototype cell in the storyboard as None. That will set the default accessory the of all the cells to None.

In the dataSource method of cellForRowAtIndexPath define your cell as

```
`let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

if(array.contains(indexPath.row)){
   cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
}
`
```

In the delegate method of didSelectRowAtIndexPath(used for- this will store the indexPaths of cells you tap and put a checkmark in their accessory type. It will add in the array only if that particular indexPath isn't already present.)

```
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if(!(array.contains(indexPath.row))){
       cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
       array.append(indexPath.row)
    } else { //to flip the state from Checkmark to None
       cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
    }  
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)     
}
```

Note: This is a fine approach only if you aren't dealing with large data set. In case you are then I would suggest you to look into Core Data  and NSFetchResultsController.